# How do we deal with prototyping in Scrum?

Tags: scrum

We are new to Scrum and part way through the first sprint we have realised that one of the team members (a developer) needs to do some investigation into how navigation should work (from a user perspective) in the application.

So at the end of this investigation we should have a proposal or prototype of how something should work.  But it wont have been actually coded in the application.

So my question is, how should we deal with something like this in terms of the sprint planning.  I don't really see it as being user story, but what is it, and how is it treated in Scrum?  Does something need to be added to the planning board for the investigation?

Thanks

Paul.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to treat prototyping like any other requirement as much as possible. Think about what you want to achieve, create a user story, define one ore several tasks and estimate them during sprint planning. Think of the development team being the user in this case. Definitely have it on the planning board and track progress in daily Scrum meetings. If you have problems estimating the tasks, define them as "time-boxed", i.e. with the fixed time budget, to prevent "endless" work without results.

Comment: Thanks Chris, it certainly seems to make sense to have these types of task on the planning board so we will try what you have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Although you got the solution Just wanted to add something here.
Such prototyping/researching works are termed as [Spikes](http://blog.agilebuddy.com/2009/11/what-is-a-spike-in-scrum.html) in the Agile world.

Here, the team dedicates some members into such spikes only so much as to understand the feasibility of the user story and be in a position to help the entire team estimate for the user story.

Answer (score 0):

SCRUM is rather an organizational process than a development model, like prototype-driven development. It means that different X-driven-development models can be easily incorporated, like TDD or even prototype-driven (PDD).

To incorporate PDD in SCRUM, one can set several milestones that are prototype versions. SCRUM can be used normally considering each prototype as a whole new project. It is good for a complex prototype.

However, if creating a prototype is very easy, and a single person can do it in one or two sprints worth of time, so it might be useful to retain a prototype-specialist, that, much like the application-specialist, monitors the work of the rest of the team to check consistency with the ultimate goal. However, a prototype specialist can iteratively provide new prototypes, guiding the work of the rest of the team in a practical manner, differently from the application specialist.